# Exclude items in a listview during multiselect enable

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am enabling multiple selection for a listview using

```
ListView.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple;
```

The multiselect works perfectly well and I am able to select/deselect elements from the list. There are certain items in the listview that I would like to exclude from selection. I would like to modify my code such that when the multiple selection is enabled, items with certain text are not available for selection in the listview.

Has anyone got some tips on how to achieve this?

EDIT:

The items are actually valid items in themselves that needs to be excluded based on the specific condition. Here is any example:

```
{"PoemId": "This is valid ID", "PoemTitle": "This is valid Title", "PoemMean": "This is valid mean"}, { "PoemId": "", "PoemTitle": "<!--Section starts here-->", "PoemMean": ""}
```

Now when I enable the multi-selection, the block with the  text should not be available for selection.

EDIT 2: For the benefits of others, here is the solution proposed by Magnus that worked for me: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/04171f22-1542-4860-81e9-0a05a7df1057/u81exclude-items-in-a-listview-during-multiselect-enable?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Is it necessary for the excluded items to still be in the list when the user is making their selection? You could create a (e.g.) list that only has the valid items and show that instead?

Comment: Yes, the excluded items must appear in the list. However, I don't want to give the user an option to select this item. That means this item can disappear when the user enable the mutliselect option. Is that possible somehow? Such items appears in different locations of the list.

Comment: Just to make sure before you go any further, are these items you want to exclude actually items directly related to the function of your app? For example, are they just `TextBlock` subtitles inserted into the list in order to split up the list, or are they actually valid items in themselves that you want to exclude based on some specific condition they hold?

Comment: @J.B Added more information in the question to help you understand the problem more clearly.

Comment: You've asked this question on MSDN, and the answer another user gave is a valid approach to do what you want. Personally, I think this approach is counter-intuitive from a users point of view. If something is in the `ListView` for multiple selection, any user would think they would be able to select it. If a user was to tap on an entry then find they it wasn't being selected, it would look like a bug (to me at least).

Comment: You say the user has the ability to enable the multi selection. Why not modify the `ListView` when this happens so that the `ListViewItem`s become greyed out? Maybe also setting their `isHitTestVisible` property to false will prevent them from being selected?

Comment: Yes, the MSDN answer is very close to what I was looking for. The good part of that approach is that it changes the items with certain properties to remain hidden from selection. I have modified it a bit to suit my requirements.